# How to configure database when converting the WPF application to browser application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I've created a solution with multiple projects. One of the projects is a WPF application, which runs fine as standalone application. It communicates with a service-application and a database.

Now I've created another WPF application, this time browser oriented. This means a user on the network should be able to approach my XBAP-page. This project seems to make use of the `aspnetdb.mdf` file. I've created that file but now the tables are incorrect, probably because of the roles and profiles being incorrect. I normally use my own Microsoft SQL Database.

I've read around on the internet and it seemed my solution (and application(s?)) need to be configured differently. I was wondering how I could get as close to the original solution as possible without changing too much. I don't want to use the `aspnetdb.mdf` but it seems like I should alter my original database file to make it work. What should I do?

Comment: I think you'll have to explain your actual problem in more detail.  "The tables are obviously incorrect" - what does that mean in developer terms?  When you say browser-oriented, do you mean XBAP?   Silverlight?  Or something entirely different?  Also, if it communicates with a service-application, why would the database be in the WPF app?

Comment: I've  updated my question a bit. As for the last part, de database isn't in the WPF but in the SQL server. I'm now trying to approach the application's interface through the webpage instead of an .exe. Apparently, the database has to be changed or reconfigured (or something else in my solution).

Comment: can't you just point your connectionstring in your web.config (or app.config for xbap) to your existing database on sql server?

Comment: How? The service project is actually the one communicating with the database while the only thing changed in the solution is the UI project. That's why it's confusing me.

Comment: and the service application is a wcf service? and how is your wpf application referencing this service application?

Comment: The WPF application is just instantiating the service. I don't have it up and running as a windows service, I'm just using it when any of the UI's is on. Then it would start the service-project. When the UI's close, so does the service.

Comment: Are you saying there is no connection string in your WPF web.config?

Comment: You say "WPF application" and "service application" - presumably these are two separate applications.  Can you outline exactly your projects, applications, services, database etc?  It's not clear at all

Comment: Please make note of the seperate words I use: project and solution. I have a WPF application which uses a service application for it's DataContext. One of the many things my Service-application contains, is a DataManger. That is being used to approach my database. My Service-application has the following connectionString in the App.config: `<add name="MicrosoftSqlServerConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=user; MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`.

Comment: My WPF-application doesn't have any connectionStrings, since there is no communication with the database there (except for the communication through the service-application). The project was working before, but when I tried to switch the WPF-application to a WPF-browser-application, the problem described in my question occurred. I hope I've provided  you with enough information, I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong or missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your WPF application already communicates with your service application. XBAP applications are restricted from using some libraries (and some ways of communication), but they support communication with WCF services or asmx server pages. Depending on the way you're already talking between your WPF application and service application, one might be easier than another.